# Projection Matrix in linear regression(and difference between Projection Matrix in linear Algebra)

Tags: regression, projection

In linear algebra class I learned, that 
$$\begin{equation*}
\hat{Y} = X \hat{\beta} = X\,\left(X^\prime X \right)^{-1} \, X^\prime Y = P\,Y
\end{equation*}$$

, where \begin{equation*}
P \equiv X\,\left(X^\prime X \right)^{-1} \, X^\prime
\end{equation*}
is a projection matrix.

But in linear model course a projection matrix is defined in another way:

\begin{equation*}
P_2 \equiv I_n- X\,\left(X^\prime X \right)^{-1} \, X^\prime
\end{equation*}

Why is so? Why in regression analysis we need projection matrix $P_2$ instead of $P$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see more often the notation

\begin{equation*}
M \equiv I_n- X\,\left(X^\prime X \right)^{-1} \, X^\prime
\end{equation*}

where $M$ is called the "annihilator" matrix, (because $MX = 0$) or "residual maker" matrix because $MY = \hat u$.

We do call $P$ the orthogonal projection matrix, and here too it holds that $
\hat Y = PY$

Answer (score 2):

A square matrix is a projection matrix if and only it is equal to its square.

You know that $P$ is a projection matrix, therefore (multiply it out), $P^2 = P$. Therefore, $P_2^2 = P_2$. Therefore $P_2$ is a projection matrix.(as is $P$).

Exercise for you: What is the relation between the subspaces to which $P$ and $P_2$ project?

Comment: They are orthogonal to each other.
I think you incorrectly understood my question(sorry for that).
I know, that $P_2$ is projection matrix.

But the question is: why do we use $P_2$ in regression analysis(in my linear model class we are using only $P_2$, instead of $P$?
Which purposes have $P$ and $P_2$?

Comment: Read pp. 5-7 as precursor, then pp. 8-10 of http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/datamining/lectures/13-reg1.pdf .

Comment: is that another way of stating idempotency or is there an important reason why you define a projection matrix as equal to its own square, rather than saying: A projection matrix is idempotent?

Comment: Idempotence of a matrix is a fancy way of saying that it equals its own square. I decided not to use terminology (a "big" word)  not everyone would know - that was a judgment call - I'm just a working class Joe at heart.